# JMS ActiveMQ consumer, when to acknowledge

Tags: spring, activemq-classic, spring-jms

I have a JMS consumer that does the following:

1. Get a message.
2. Process the message.
3. Acknowledge the message.

Is it OK to wait a long period of time between getting and acknowledge the message? Processing the message might takes up to *24 hours*.

Using Java, Spring JMS, ActiveMQ, and `CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE` mode on a Windows server.

Comment: At a very quick glance 'I don't see why not' BUT... remember any un-ack'd message will be re-delivered in the event the client reconnects, or a new client connects to the same destination. Depending on your message rate you may need to look at the storage limits so you don't end up with an OOM condition.

Comment: Did my answer address your question? If so, please mark it as correct to help other users who have this same question in the future. If not, please elaborate as to why. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's technically OK to wait that long to acknowledge the message. However, you may face issues with delivery of the same message multiple times and *a lot* of wasted resources.

Consider a situation where your client gets a message that will take 24 hours to process but it fails (for whatever reason) at hour 23 and doesn't acknowledge the message. The unacknowledged message will be delivered to another consumer where presumably all the work done for 23 hours by the other consumer will be repeated. This process could potentially repeat many times each time essentially wasting a days worth of resources.

Comment: Depending on the broker this can also lead to massive store growth as the journal may not be able to clean up logs until days later.